# Replacing the system partition without touching the kernel?

Tags: rom-flashing, kernel, system

So I have an android phone that I'd like to put a clean rom onto, but it looks like there aren't any good kernels ported to it yet. I've done some reading into the android architecture, and come to the conclusion that it could be possible to simply leave the kernel as-is, and flash a new (standard) system on the device.

Is this idea at all viable, or am I missing something? And if it is viable, does anyone have any tips to how I might go about it?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: I've got an inexpensive chinese model [this one](http://aud.dx.com/product/jxiaomai-mote3-mtk6582-ouad-core-android-4-3-3-phone-w-5-0-wvga-wi-fi-otg-black-961316555#.U4K1RCiDrUx). Has one of them MTK chips, but the customized android they have on it is really rubbish however.

Answer (score 1):

It is viable, as there are custom ROMs I've seen that contains the original kernel but different system files.
There is a catch though: If for example your device ships with CyanogenMod and you want to put PA on it, you'll have to get your hands dirty with the ramdisk as each ROM needs slightly different init* files to boot.

As for installing the ROM, you'll need to put it in a ZIP file and include a `META-INF` folder which will contain the files responsible for the correct ROM flash, e.g. `updater-script`.

The full procedure is too long to mention here, so I'd say you should head over to [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com) to get the info you need.

Comment: I'd definitely have up-voted this if the XDA link pointed to a specific page rather than just the site.

Comment: @mc0e Oh, sorry. I couldn't find a thread that's perfectly suited for this (or I wasn't looking hard enough). Either way, I'll just make my own thread in a few days and update this answer with the link. :D

Comment: No need to apologise.  Was just saying...